# BitBlt issues with Memory DC created from printer DC

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

i have an issue with a fix i made to allow a flood filled object be printed...

so, the full story is we were using the windows GDI FloodFill function, which we noticed doesnt work on printers, so what i found on the inet, was to create a memory DC, compatible with the printer DC, and make all my drawing operations on the memory DC, and then BitBlt it all at once to the printer DC (i had to change to use a recursive, color replacment flood fill function too, since the memory DC only allows what the main DC did)

the problem is the memory DC seems to be a pixel or two bigger on the x and y, but i dont know what to do, when i get the selected bitmap from the memory DC, it shows it to be the correct size, i would like to use StretchBlt, but the values i have access to use as params for StretchBlt, make it no different than calling BitBlt

let me know if you need more info...

thanks in advance!!!

heres my code:

```
HDC hMemPrnDC = CreateCompatibleDC (hPrnDC);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap (hPrnDC, iWidthLP, iHeightLP);
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = SelectBitmap (hMemPrnDC, hBitmap);

    // paint the whole memory DC with the window color
HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush (GetSysColor (COLOR_WINDOW));
RECT rect;
    // add one to right and bottom, FillRect doesnt include the right and bottom edges
SetRect (&rect, 0, 0, iWidthLP + 1, iHeightLP + 1);
    // NOTE: im doing this cause it starts out as all black
FillRect (hMemPrnDC, &rect, hBrush);

    // delete object
DeleteBrush (hBrush);

//
// do all my MoveToEx, LineTo, Ellipse, Arc, TextOut,
// SetPixel, etc calls on hMemPrnDC here
//

    // copy all the memory DC drawing data to the printer DC
BitBlt (hPrnDC, 0, 0, iWidthLP, iHeightLP, hMemPrnDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // select old bitmap, and clean up objects
SelectBitmap (hMemPrnDC, hOldBitmap);
DeleteBitmap (hBitmap);
DeleteDC (hMemPrnDC);
hMemPrnDC = NULL;
```

UPDATE (Sept 5):

here is a link to a PDF print where I draw straight to the printer DC:
[hPrnDC.pdf](http://www.winsim.com/stackoverflow/hPrnDC.pdf)

and here is the same but I draw to the memory DC then BitBlt it to the printer DC:
[hMemPrnDC.pdf](http://www.winsim.com/stackoverflow/hMemPrnDC.pdf)

now, I did enable my recursive flood fill function on the second, to show an example of what we are trying to achieve, it does the same without it, so that is not an issue

as you can see, the bottom and right edge are cut off, I'm also concerned about the differences in font & line weight between the two, but not as much as the sizing mismatch

NOTE: the filename printed at the top doesn't go through the memory DC, that is always drawn straight to the printer DC

Comment: What do you mean by "a pixel or two bigger"? What results are you seeing?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see your post until today

here is a link to a PDF print where I draw straight to the printer DC:
[link](http://www.winsim.com/stackoverflow/hPrnDC.pdf)

& here is the same but I draw to the memory DC then BitBlt it to the printer DC:
[link](http://www.winsim.com/stackoverflow/hMemPrnDC.pdf)

now, I did enable my recursive flood fill function on the 2nd, to show an example of what we are trying to achieve

you can see, the bttm and right edge are cut off, I'm also concerned about the difference in font & line weight, but not as much as the sizing mismatch

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: You're explicitly setting the rectangle to 1 greater than the size. Why are you surprised that it's coming out 1 pixel larger?

Comment: Yes, I tried that just in case, the same results happened, but the reason I left the `+ 1` is that is the correct way to paint the entire rectangle: `{0, 0, iWidthLP, iHeightLP}`, because the "FillRect...function includes the left and top borders, but excludes the right and bottom borders of the rectangle." Source: [MSDN: FillRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162719.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem, more of a work-around, but it achieved the desired results...

I only used the memory DC as a go between on the items that needed the recursive flood fill (GetPixel and SetPixel), so I draw them first to the memory DC, copy it all over to the printer DC and then draw everything else straight to the printer DC, seems to work just fine

thanks for the help!